# Shifting array Values PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Please Help me. I have And Following array :

```
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Name
        [1] => Age
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Name 1
        [1] => 20
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => Name 2
        [1] => 21
        )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => Name 3
        [1] => 22
        )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => Name 4
        [1] => 23
        )
    [5] => Array (
        [0] => Name 5
        [1] => 24
        )
```

I want to achieve shift the values of array  like this output:

Because when exporting excel file into php database values will insert incorrectly with shifting of 1 row of age:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => Name
    [1] => 20
    )
[1] => Array (
    [0] => Name 1
    [1] => 21
    )
[2] => Array (
    [0] => Name 2
    [1] => 22
    )
[3] => Array (
    [0] => Name 3
    [1] => 23
    )
[4] => Array (
    [0] => Name 4
    [1] => 24
    )
[5] => Array (
    [0] => Name 5
    [1] => 25
    )
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What you have is a string in an array, which you're shifting out again, so `$a === $array`, which is a string.

Comment: Actually it is array.. I put this as a string here.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯…?? So we don't really have any idea what your actual code is what you're really doing…

Comment: @shachigandhi  your input data is array or string?If it's array do you want like this:- https://eval.in/1001326

Comment: checkout updated questing.... I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is what you want? The original array looks like a pretty standard CSV structure, with a header row containing "Name" and "Age". Is the original Excel file wrong? If so, fix the source rather than bodge the import process.

Comment: Did you look in the php manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop then check for the last array key

```
$array = [
    ["Name","Age"], ["Name 1","20"], ["Name 2","23"], ["Name 3","30"],
    ["Name 4","20"], ["Name 5","26"], ["Name 6","27"], ["Name 7","21"], ["Name 8","26"]
    ];

// Get last array key using count() or you can use end() then key()
$last_key = count($array) - 1; 

$result = []; // initialize result array

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $last_key) break;                       // if last key, break loop
    $result[] = [ $array[$key][0], $array[++$key][1] ]; // push name, age+1 values
}

print_r($result);
```